# Are the functions $f:[1,2]\to (0,1)$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ I defined bijective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I defined functions $f:[1,2]\to (0,1)$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}$ as follows:

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1/2 & x=1\\
1/3 & x=2\\
1/(n+2) & \exists n \in \mathbb N^+ (x=1+1/n)\\
x-1 & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

$$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
-2x-1 & x \in \mathbb N\\
2x & \exists n \in \mathbb N^+ (x=-n)\\
x & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

I showed that they're bijective by considering all possible cases (and proving by contradiction that some can't occur - in the injectivity proof). My question is: are they really bijections? If so, is there any simpler way to prove it?

Comment: They are bijections, yes.  One way to simplify the proof is, to combine cases 2 and 3 in your definition of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

They are bijections. I think there's no simpler way to complete the proof, for you must deal with the conditions that maps the integers since they are *special* from the others. They're nice constructions tho.

Answer (score 0):

Bijectivity of $f$ can be shown as follows without a lot of case work. Let $A=\left\{1+\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$; $f\upharpoonright A$ is the composition of the translation $x\mapsto x-1$, the reciprocal map, the translation $n\mapsto n+2$, and the reciprocal map, each of which is injective, so it must be a bijection between $A$ and $f[A]$. Similarly, $f\upharpoonright\big([1,2]\setminus(A\cup\{1,2\})\big)$ is injective, so it must be a bijection between its domain and range, which is easily verified to be $(0,1)\setminus\left\{\frac13,\frac12\right\}$.

Similarly, bijectivity of $g$ is immediate once you show that $g\upharpoonright\Bbb Z$ is a bijection to $\Bbb Z^-$.